# React getInitialProps req on server failed: uncaught promise: GET (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, nodes

Problem with fectich data from Express server on `getIntitalProps`

This is `getCurrentUser` reqeust which is triggered:

```
export const getCurrentUser = () => http('/api/current-user');
```

Here is req where is sent:

```
 static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    if (req) {
      return { roles: req.user.roles };
    }
    const { userRoles } = getCurrentUser();
    return { roles: userRoles };
  }
```

Dont know how to fix this problem with promise?

ERORR: 
[image: es]

Comment: `getInitialProps` only runs server side, you need to show us the server logs not the client logs

Comment: For one, the resource `/api/current-user` results in a 404 error, so there's no express route that sends back a result. Next, you probably need `const { userRoles } = await getCurrentUser();`

Comment: check the route in your expres server , cause it returns 404 , whether you're wrong on route or just the server is down ?

Comment: OK I will check now

Comment: Route works, separetly, and If I put this in `ComponentDidMount` this will work.
Problem is in promise or way of using `getInitalProps`. 
`const { userRoles } = await getCurrentUser();`